# JSch shell channel - Won't close after disconnecting

Tags: java, shell, jsch

I'm connecting to a remote machine using JSch. In order to restart a service, I need to have su privileges, so I'm using a shell channel instead of exec. I'm able to run the commands just fine, but once I disconnect the channel and session, application gets stuck and the execution doesn't move forward. I need to Ctrl-C to kill the application.

Am I doing anything wrong in my method?

```
public static void sendCommandWithSudo(String user, String pass, String ip, String command) {

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, ip, 22);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(pass);

        System.out.println("IP Address: " + ip);
        System.out.println("Username: " + user);
        System.out.println("Password: " + pass);
        System.out.println("Command issued: " + command);

        UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
        session.setUserInfo(ui);

        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        PrintStream shellStream = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

        channel.connect(3*1000);

        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        commands.add("sudo su - sudouser");
        commands.add(command);


        for(String cmd: commands) {
            shellStream.println(cmd);
            shellStream.flush();
        }

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

        shellStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replying to myself:
Adding the exit command twice seems to solve this:

```
commands.add("sudo su - sudouser");
commands.add(command);
commands.add("exit");
commands.add("exit");
```